# How to start the Laravel application in Localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

App Structure

- ovss
- - vsdapp
- - vsd

I am coming from ReactJs and not able to start the app in the local server xampp.

Following steps, I performed

1. Downloaded the folders in htdocs in xampp
2. Run composer update

if I run cmd PHP artisan serve, I get a public path error and if I run code in xampp, then no file found please have a look at the following pictures for reference.

I am new to Laravel and will be studying this soon but right now have to start a local project.

**App Structure**

[image: App Structure]

**vsdapp not found**

[image: vsdapp not found]

**cmd php artisan serve giving this error**

[image: cmd php artisan serve giving this error]

**vsdapp files**

[image: vsdapp files]

**vsd files**

[image: vsd files]

Comment: did you run `php artisn serve`

Comment: Please share more details about the VHost configuration. Also, what do you mean by "Downloaded the folders in htdocs in xampp"?

Comment: The public folder is missing from the vsdapp project directory.

Comment: @Basharmal yes!

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the base URL to localhost.